# How can I change filename format of the archived org file

Tags: org-mode

In this answer related to [How to archive all the DONE tasks using a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043756/2402577):

> ```
> (defun org-archive-done-tasks ()
>   (interactive)
>   (org-map-entries
>    (lambda ()
>      (org-archive-subtree)
>      (setq org-map-continue-from (org-element-property :begin (org-element-at-point))))
>    "/DONE" 'tree))
> ```

I am able to all the `DONE` tasks into `<filename>.org_archive` file. I have `_archive` is automatically added to the original filename.

If my file name is `TODO.org`, it archive file name would be `TODO.org_archive`.

---

Would it be possible to change the format of the archive file name such as making it as hidden file as `.TODO.org_archive` or `archive_TODO.org`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stuff is in the documentation: If you search the Org manual for `archive` (do `C-h i g(org)RET i archive`), you'll end up in a section that says:

> The default archive location is a file in the same directory as the
> current file, with the name derived by appending ‘_archive’ to the
> current file name.  You can also choose what heading to file archived
> items under, with the possibility to add them to a datetree in a file.
> For information and examples on how to specify the file and the heading,
> see the documentation string of the variable ‘org-archive-location’.

Checking the doc string of the variable mentioned (with `C-h v org-archive-location`) shows this:

> org-archive-location is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
>
> Its value is "%s_archive::"
>
> The location where subtrees should be archived.
>
> The value of this variable is a string, consisting of two parts,
> separated by a double-colon.  The first part is a filename and
> the second part is a headline.
>
> ...

Furthermore, it shows examples of how you might want to customize it. That should allow you to do what you want.

Note that if you learn how to search the manuals and the doc strings that Emacs provides, you can answer questions like this quickly and efficiently (and in much less time than it takes to post a question on Stack Exchange and wait for an answer). After all, Emacs is supposed to be *self-documenting*, so it behooves you to learn how to use its documentation features: `C-h i m info` is a good first step.

Comment: Thanks even with your guide it took some time for me to find the related text in the manual, I should spend more time in the manual to get used to it :-)

Comment: As I mentioned, `C-h i m info`: reading that is a good first step. After that, practice, practice, practice: the more you practice, the easier it gets and then you don't even think about it any more: you have a question and your fingers take over and get you to the answer :-)

Comment: I wonder does linux kernel manual uses emacs's manual format, its pretty neat

Comment: It does not. The `Documentation` tree in the kernel is a bunch of text files. A lof of the developers are not Emacs users.

Comment: How can I save changes on the `org-archive-location`? I have done `Apply and Save` but it did not make any change on the config file :-(

Comment: You might have a separate file where customizations are saved. Check the value of `custom-file`.

Comment: its value is something called: `"/run/user/1000/emacs/custom.el"` I had no idea that file exists

Comment: This  kind of pathname usually indicates a file on a removable device (like a USB stick). You probably want to copy the custom file to some more permanent place (like `~/.emacs.d/custom.el` perhaps) and change the setting of the variable to point to it.

Comment: Hm I have `(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/config/customize.el") (load-file custom-file)` in my config file but it does not apply this to the `custom-file`'s path. I will investigate this from the manual

Comment: I applied following solution (https://config.daviwil.com/emacs#keep-emacsd-clean), I believe that was the main cause